# How to do long space in Mathematica 11.3

Tags: formatting, unicode

In some previous versions of Mathematica under Windows 10 you could type \:2003 and a long space (Unicode em space character) appeared, e.g. inside a text cell.

This does not seem to work in version 11.3.

Any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Try out `\:2003`

Comment: Yep, that's what I typed, but the Q got typeset with :2003 instead of \:2003.

Comment: On my Mac with v11.3 using `\:2003` I get: **This is a test of a long space**.

Comment: Thanks, should have added "under Windows 10", will do that now.

Comment: Not much help to you, but it works on my Mathematica 11.3 under Linux Mint.

Comment: You could try Control+Shift+E to view the textual representation of the cell.  You can then type "\:2003" at the appropriate point.  Control+Shift+E again should return you to see the formatted expression.  On my Linux PC, this gives me a long space (not tested on Windows).

Comment: It does work for me with version 11.3 under windows, did you try different stylesheets?

Comment: mikado, the Ctrl-Shift-E thing is cool but it does not solve it for me.

Coolwater, it does seem to have to do with the stylesheet (which is the Default one), because changing to basically any other one makes it work! Thank you.